# Failed finishing setup for store during asynchronous iCloud initialization

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I am in the process of creating a core data stack in Swift 2 that handles syncing data with other iDevices using iCloud using different resources (Mostly in Objective-C).

When running the app I sometimes get the following error, and if I run it again the error goes but sometimes displays old data that was supposed to be deleted:

```
2015-09-08 22:49:31.104 APPNAME[5606:418539]
-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](874): CoreData: Ubiquity: 
nobody~sim73E13D94-AB95-59FB-AF18-ADC7BC05B47B:APPNAMEStore Using local
storage: 1 for new NSFileManager current token <766b5e5c 3c205110
52c05248 38a47bd9 aca1ee87> 2015-09-08 22:49:31.185
APPNAME[5606:418593] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant
finishSetupForStore:error:](1125): CoreData: Ubiquity:  CoreData:error: Caught Exception Unable to resolve mismatching KVs with
userInfo {

PFUbiquitySetupDoFork = 1; } in -finishSetupForSet:error: 2015-09-08 22:49:31.243 APPNAME[5606:418593] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant
finishSetupWithRetry:](829): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquitySetupAssistant: 0x7f97b3328320>: Retrying after delay: 60

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 "(null)" UserInfo={failed finishing setup for store during asynchronous iCloud 
initialization=file:///Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19DE5FBA-9248-410D-9264-6B434B30F8CA/data/Containers/Data/Application/5B174D0D-C80D-4362-90EE-DC640F907962/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/nobody~sim73E13D94-AB95-59FB-AF18-ADC7BC05B47B/APPNAMEStore/DD2F75D5-FEAF-482A-A896-657936AFCFCD/store/APPNAME.sqlite}
2015-09-08 22:50:31.288 APPNAME[5606:418966] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupForStore:error:](1125): CoreData: Ubiquity:  CoreData: error: Caught Exception Unable to resolve mismatching KVs with userInfo {
    PFUbiquitySetupDoFork = 1; } in -finishSetupForSet:error: 2015-09-08 22:50:31.289 APPNAME[5606:418966]
-[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant
finishSetupWithRetry:](829): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquitySetupAssistant: 0x7f97b3328320>: Retrying after delay: 120 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 "(null)" UserInfo={failed finishing setup for store during asynchronous iCloud 
initialization=file:///Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19DE5FBA-9248-410D-9264-6B434B30F8CA/data/Containers/Data/Application/5B174D0D-C80D-4362-90EE-DC640F907962/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/nobody~sim73E13D94-AB95-59FB-AF18-ADC7BC05B47B/APPNAMEStore/DD2F75D5-FEAF-482A-A896-657936AFCFCD/store/APPNAME.sqlite}
2015-09-08 22:52:31.333 APPNAME[5606:420217] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupForStore:error:](1125): CoreData: Ubiquity:  CoreData: error: Caught Exception Unable to resolve mismatching KVs with userInfo {
    PFUbiquitySetupDoFork = 1; } in -finishSetupForSet:error:
```

**Core Data Stack**

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

// This handles the updates to the data via iCLoud updates
func registerCoordinatorForStoreNotifications (coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator) {
let nc : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();

nc.addObserver(self, selector: "StoresWillChange:",
    name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification,
    object: coordinator)

nc.addObserver(self, selector: "StoresDidChange:",
    name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,
    object: coordinator)

nc.addObserver(self, selector: "StoreChangedUbiquitousContent:",
    name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification,
    object: coordinator)
}


// Subscribe to NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
// most likely to be called if the user enables / disables iCloud
// (either globally, or just for your app) or if the user changes
// iCloud accounts.

func StoresWillChange (notification:NSNotification) {
managedObjectContext.performBlock { () -> Void in
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("error saving Managed Object Context in AppDelegate")
        }

        } else{
            // drop any manged object refrences
            self.managedObjectContext.reset()
        }

      }
  }

   // Subscribe to  NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification
 func StoresDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
  NSLog("storesDidChange posting notif");
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("storeDidChange", object: nil)
}

func mergeChanges(notification: NSNotification) {
NSLog("mergeChanges notif:\(notification)")
    self.managedObjectContext.performBlock {
        self.managedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
}

func StoreChangedUbiquitousContent(notification: NSNotification) {
self.mergeChanges(notification);
}


lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
// The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.USER.swift2-iCloud" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("APPNAME", withExtension: "momd")!
return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!

}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

// Create the coordinator and store
var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? =    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("APPNAME.sqlite")
var error: NSError? = nil
var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
// iCloud store
var storeOptions = [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "APPNAMEStore",NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

do {
    try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(url.path!), options: storeOptions)
} catch var error1 as NSError {
    error = error1
    coordinator = nil
    // Report any error we got.
    var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
    dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
    dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
    dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
    error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
    // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    abort()
} catch {
    fatalError()
}

self.registerCoordinatorForStoreNotifications (coordinator!)

return coordinator
}()
```

Does anybody understand why this is occurring and how I can resolve the error ? I really appreciate feedback as I am hoping to create a public GitHub repository for other new developers to use.

Comment: If you are using beta versions then this is most likely a bug.  I have seen this some times but it seems to go away and things eventually sync OK.

Comment: BTW make sure you have the latest version of XCode 7 beta

Comment: Any progress made on this? I'm using the Public build of XCode 7 and still getting this

Comment: @StevenRitchie nope :( took a break from iCloud as I cannot find a solution. working on other things then will come back to it.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with the released version of Xcode 7.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same issue in Xcode 7.1. In my app, I implemented the Core Data stack given in the link provided by @daleijn in his answer. Even though it is true that most iCloud errors are rather scary but have no real consequences, the error from the questions is the only one which produces my data to stop syncing and in the end, ending up corrupted. So, unfortunately, this error truly is real. I find myself in the same situation and still couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't leave it as a comment, cuz wrote here. Found reply about this issue [here](http://iaintheindie.com/2014/07/07/icloud-core-data-part-3-complete-stack/)

*In terms of those iCloud errors that appear, they generally look a lot scarier than they are. My experience has been that iCloud is great at generating a lot of very scary looking messages in the log that don’t actually signal anything is wrong. In most cases the errors automatically correct themselves after a time. The most intervention I have needed to do at times has been when using the iOS simulator where at times you need to reset the computer to fix it.
However, there are some things that can cause iCloud containers to become corrupted. If you are performing a lot of synchronisation testing, in particular operations that generate a lot of duplicates, it can take an extended time for the iCloud container to properly sync.
You also need to be careful that any, and I do mean any, accessing of the information held in Core Data is handled from the same thread. That includes reading from the objects that you have loaded from Core Data. Accessing the information from multiple threads can very easily cause corruption that does not manifest until you try to sync the container (or migrate it). The best way to avoid that is to use the `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` methods on the iCloud + Core Data stack. Those methods guarantee that the operations (read or write) will happen on the same thread to prevent data corruption.*